# Change The Color of Boolean Indicator

Tags: labview

[image: front panel and block diagram showing LED indicator]

I want to change the color of the boolean indicator to red, yellow, green, or blue when the user presses the respective button. Additionally, I want to save the LED image to disk as a *.jpg.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [NI knowledgebase](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/7DC619797D9455E286256EE3008221E0), you need to write to the `Colors [4]` property of the indicator - in your code you appear to be writing to a parameter of the `Get Image` method.

> The Colors [4] property actually uses an array of clusters containing
>   two U32 numeric elements.  The two elements of each cluster are
>   foreground and background RGB (Red, Green, Blue) colors for specific
>   components of the control or indicator.  The first element in the
>   cluster of the first element of the array is the Boolean False case
>   color.  The first element in the cluster of the second element of the
>   array is the True color case.

As the link describes, you can supply these `U32` values from color box constants as you're already using in your code. Also, while the NI example shows a `Bool Refnum` control wired to a `Bool (Strict)` property node, because your LED is on the same diagram you don't need to do this: you can just create a property node for your LED and select the `Colors [4]` property.

For what it's worth, the knowledgebase page was the first hit when I searched the web for *labview change color boolean indicator*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `colors[4]` property of each of the buttons, as you already have them in the colour you want the LED to be.

I also placed the `stop` and the `save` buttons inside the event manager. In your example you would have to trigger an event before the stop instructions was read, and you would save an image every time you change the colour of the .LED.

Bellow is the [code snippet](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/9330/en/), just drag and drop the image into a blank VI and you should get the code (done in LabVIEW version 2015).

[image]